# What is the best way to run a Docker Container? Cron, or other means? With multiple source files it has to pull from?

Tags: shell-script, cron, docker

I am looking to run multiple instances of my docker container, and have each container re-run every 30 minutes.

I have a conf file in a src directory the docker container needs to pull from to be able to run. For example

Usage:

```
docker run -v ~/example.com/conf:/opt/tool/conf --rm -it sdok
```

Where example.com/conf: is the place the container will need to pull the conf file from in order to run.

I have multiple example.com directories... 3-4 of them.

My bash script would look something like:

sdok.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home
docker run -v ~/example.com/conf:/opt/tool/conf --rm -it sdok
docker run -v ~/example.com1/conf:/opt/tool/conf --rm -it sdok
docker run -v ~/example.com2/conf:/opt/tool/conf --rm -it sdok
docker run -v ~/example.com3/conf:/opt/tool/conf --rm -it sdok
docker run -v ~/example.com4/conf:/opt/tool/conf --rm -it sdok
```

After, I would just cron the sdok.sh script and let it run every 30 minutes. Is there a better way to do this?

```
*/30 * * * * cd /home/wraiith75/bugbounty/tool/example.com && ./sdok.sh
```

Please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. Why `-it`? `-d` would be more appropriate
2. With `--rm` you lose the logs, and won't have a clue in case of problems.
3. Using a `docker-compose` file instead of a script could be better (you keep restarting the same containers, and keep the logs)
4. If you keep the bash script you can write it as a loop over your example.com* directories.